# Parsing JSON in PHP error

Tags: php, json, parsing

I want to parse this JSON:

```
{
   "date":[
      "dia_29_06_13"
   ],
   "jsonList":{
      "__type":"File",
      "name":"d138af3c-4da0-4ab9-b3ff-0ac09a352fd8-lista.json",
   "localName":[
      "Patropi"
   ],
   "pspReference":"8513723597141689",
   "qrcode":"KWX35ERoNJ",
   "status":"true",
   "valor":127,
   "createdAt":"2013-06-27T19:01:46.830Z",
   "updatedAt":"2013-06-27T19:01:57.830Z",
   "objectId":"fcXMwYaDMQ",
   "ACL":{
      "*":{
         "write":true,
         "read":true
      },
      "KWX35ERoNJ":{
         "write":true,
         "read":true
      }
   }
}
```

But it always give me this error:

```
date: 0: => dia_29_06_13
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/storage/a/1c/6e/semhora/public_html/payment/temp3.php on line 42
```

I am using this code:

```
$response = curl_exec($rest);

        $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($response)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key: => $val";

    }
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($val);`, not `echo`

Comment: close `}` one more at the end for valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you expect nested items to be arrays - you need to parse it into array:

```
json_decode($response, true)
```

When the second parameter is set to `true` - the JSON string will be parsed to an array, not `stdClass`

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you have posted above is not valid.

Check it on [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/).

You open one more curly brace than you close.

Comment: As soon as OP sees "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" errror - it means the JSON is valid (and here we just see  copy-paste typo)